# preg_match not working with ^ and $

Tags: php

I use `preg_match` for testing unicode pattern with symbols and digits.

```js
$reg = '/^(?=.*\p{L})[\d\p{L}]+$/im';
$str = trim('станция44');

if (preg_match($reg, $str) === 1) {
    echo 'Match';
} else {
    echo 'Not match';
}
```

If I test it I get `Not match` but if I remove `^ and $` I get `Match`. Why it is happen?

Comment: Seems to work if you add the Unicode flag at the end... `/ ... /imu`

Comment: Thanks! It is work for me! Can you post you comment in major answers I select as best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `p{L}` matching you need to add the Unicode modifier (`u`) at the end:

```
$reg = '/^(?=.*\p{L})[\d\p{L}]+$/imu';
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php